# Add sign in/out button to sidebar according to current session value

Tags: angular, angular8

I want to add sign out to this sidebar if my session value is true.
And sign out if session "auth" value is false.

This is my sidebar.component.ts code.

```
import { AlertService } from './../../services/alerts';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SessionService } from 'app/services/session';

declare interface RouteInfo {
  path: string;
  title: string;
  icon: string;
  class: string;
  id: string;
}
export const ROUTES: RouteInfo[] = [
  { path: '/dashboard', id: 'dashboard', title: 'Dashboard', icon: 'dashboard', class: '' },
  { path: '/mostpopular', id: 'mostpopular', title: 'Most Popular Poems', icon: 'content_paste', class: '' },
  { path: '/poet', id: 'poet', title: 'Poets', icon: 'library_books', class: '' },
  { path: '/notifications', id: 'notification', title: 'Notifications', icon: 'notifications', class: '' },
  { path: '/user-profile', id: 'user', title: 'User Profile', icon: 'person', class: '' },
  { path: '/writepoem', id: 'writepoem', title: 'Write a Poem', icon: 'bubble_chart', class: 'sidebarunique' },   
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
   menuItems: any[];
   constructor(private session: SessionService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.menuItems = ROUTES.filter(menuItem => menuItem);

   var auth =  this.session.getAuth();

   /*
      Need to add sign in/out button according to the 'auth' value

    */
  }

}
```

I can get current auth value using "this.session.getAuth();" If the user already signed in I want to display sign out button.

Comment: Consider using `Subject`. you can use it as a global variable to store the `loggedIn` state.  If it's value changes then all components subscribing to it also know about the changes.

Comment: Can i get a link to study more about subjects please. Im new to angular

Comment: this should help. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`*ngIf` directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) in your template, it add an element to DOM if the expression return true and remove it from DOM if the expression return false:

```
<button *ngIf="auth">Sign Out</button>

<button *ngIf="!auth">Sign In</button>
```

Comment: Do I have to try this in html file??

Comment: Yes, it is an element in your `sidebar.component.html`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you